# I can't add work areas in GNOME flashback Ubuntu 14.04 or make Alt+Tab work

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, workspaces, gnome-classic

I have been dealing with this <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> problem for a long time. I have already checked keyboard shortcuts in the configuration panel but it still doesn't work.

I had this problem in Ubuntu 12.04, but since I installed 14.04 another problem appeared too. I can't add work spaces. I tried changing the number of work areas by right clicking in the desktop's miniature but it doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

These are two questions. You should ask separately.
Regarding workspaces, try:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/num-workspaces 8
```

in a terminal. It will create 8 workspaces

Answer (score 1):

About the workspaces, you also have to change it in *compizconfig-settings-manger*. Run **ccsm** in a terminal:

```
ccsm
```

Click in *General*, then *General Options*, click the *Desktop Size* tab, change the horizontal and vertical size there as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the alt+tab question, all I can advise is for you to install Compiz Settings Manager. Open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-default
```

After installing you can launch it with

```
ccsm
```

Scroll down to Window Management and enable "Static Application Switcher". As for the work areas, I can't help. I have that same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problems when using flashback compiz.
I now use flashback metacity and everything works off the shell as expected.

Make sure that the package 'metacity' is installed (either through synaptic or apt-get command line)
Now when you login, you first click the little circle that's to the above right of the password field. You get some options here and there is a  choice for metacity. You pick that; you get returned to the password screen.
Enter your password; that should do the trick.

(When you usually login automatically (as I do), logout first to get to the login screen)

Comment: Please explain, how to do that (see [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot provide a screenshot. If someone can tell me how to grab the login screen, please do!