# Multiple workspaces in Ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME flashback

Tags: gnome, compiz, workspaces

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME flashback. I am unable to get multiple workspaces in the Compiz version of GNOME flashback.

I have tried the solutions in [add workspaces with gnome classic and ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519651/add-workspaces-with-gnome-classic-and-ubuntu-14-04) and [I can't add work areas in gnome flashback ubuntu 14.04 or make the alt-tab work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476296/i-cant-add-work-areas-in-gnome-flashback-ubuntu-14-04-or-make-the-alt-tab-work).

The solution using the dconf command is not working and even though the solution using the compiz config settings manager gives me multiple workspaces, the applications that are opened in all workspaces toggle when using ALT+TAB. Typically, only the applications within the current workspace toggle with the ALT+TAB. Any suggestions on what to do next?

Thanks in advance!